# Dynamically generating the name of the function to call

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to call a function when the name of the function is decided at the runtime? For example, calling `pdf` would look like:

```
pdf("myfile.pdf")
```

but is there a way, I could do something like:

```
media_type = "pdf"
media_type("myfile.pdf")
```

Comment: write an R package, and library(my_package).

Comment: One way to do this would be to use a *lookup table*, which maps the filetype string to the appropriate function. (Or, a switch/if-else construct.) Not sure how a lookup table would work in R, though.

Comment: It looks like [this is possible](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.1.6/topics/switch_lang) (since R supports anonymous functions); However, I don't understand the docs I just linked. Good luck! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**1) do.call** Use `do.call`

```
do.call(media_type, list("myfile.pdf"))
```

**2) match.fun** Another approach is `match.fun`

```
fun <- match.fun(media_type)
fun("myfile.pdf")
```

**3) switch** Another approach is the following where an argument to `switch` would be added for each media type.  `stop` is the default. It generates an error when called.

```
fun <- switch(media_type, pdf = pdf, stop)
fun("myfile.pdf")
```

**4) eval/call** This also works although the use of `eval` is generally frowned upon:

```
eval(call(media_type, "myfile.pdf"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're wanting, but given the example in your question, it is possible.  Assuming you have code that determines which function you want to call, you can use `do.call` to pass in the string based function name. I had to wrap the input in a list to make it happy, but that's not a big deal most of the time.

```
f = "mean"
d = c(1,2,3)
do.call(f,list(d))
#> 2
```